# Rails Active Record Query - problems retrieving a single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My goal is to return a single object in a Rails Active Record query.  I want to retrieve the most recent record when the table is sorted by the created_at date. So, in the example below, that means I want to return the record with the ID of 2. I don't understand why the 4 queries below all return the same result?

**Sales Table Records**

```
 +----+---------+-------+------------+----------------------------+
 | ID | user_id | price | sale_date  |         created_at         |
 +----+---------+-------+------------+----------------------------+
 |  1 |       1 |   200 | 2012-08-07 | 2012-10-02 23:01:46.706727 |
 |  2 |       1 |   400 | 2009-05-11 | 2012-10-02 23:09:01.342879 |
 +----+---------+-------+------------+----------------------------+
```

**Queries:**

```
 <%= current_user.sales.order("created_at").last.price %>
```

returns: 200

```
 <%= current_user.sales.order("created_at DESC").last.price %>
```

returns: 200

```
 <%= current_user.sales.order("created_at ASC").last.price %>
```

returns: 200

```
 <%= current_user.sales.last.price %>
```

returns: 200

I also tried:

```
 <%= current_user.sales.last("created_at").price %>
```

returns: `undefined method 'assert_valid_keys' for "created_at":String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Sale` class has a default_scope defined, and it includes an `order` clause, then you may use

```
.reorder("created_at DESC")
```

instead of

```
.order("created_at DESC")
```

Comment: Wow, that was it.  I don't know how you guessed that without seeing my model, but nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this magic incantation if you will:

```
current_user.sales.sort_by(&:created_at).last
```